# Can't parse json format to ajax

Tags: javascript, json, flask

I tried all the ways but still can't easily parse a json back to ajax.
either I can't get the response value or the object length is too long (when i put breakpoint to troubleshoot).
only that response works when I tried "return jsonify(status[0])", but I don't think it's a good way to list out all into jsonify.

```js
url:"/Verify_form",
              type:"post",
              contentType:'application/json',
              dataType: "json",
              processData:false,
              async: false,
              success:function(response){
                       if (response == "success"){
                          alert("[Success] - Verify Form !!!" );
                          action = 2;} 
                        else if (response["failed"]) {alert(response["msg"])}
                        else  {
                              var len = Object.keys(response).length;
                              var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select[id=select_host]");
                              if (len == 1) {
                                for (var index = 0; index < selects.length ; index++)
                                if (selects[index].value == response["hostname"])
                                BLINK(stage[index]);
                              }
                              else if (len > 1){
                              for( var ind = 0; ind < len; ind++){
                                for (var index = 0; index < selects.length ; index++)
                                  {
```

```py
                cur=g.db.execute('update table set status=(\'%s\') where hostname=(\'%s\')'
                %("error",i))
                g.db.commit()

            cur=g.db.execute('select hostname from table where mac_address <> \'\' AND status=(\'error\') ')
            status = [dict(hostname=row[0]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
            app_json = json.dumps(status)
            ## return jsonify(app_json) ## Error - len in break point equal 37  
            ## return jsonify(status[0]) ## success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console the ajax response and see in all cases (success,failed ..), weather it is proper `JSON` format or not.
If response is in valid `JSON` format, `parse` it first, then read the keys.